# Getting init parameter while accessing JSP file by filename

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, servlets

I'm trying to access init parameter in a JSP file.
When I enter a url-pattern from servlet mapping like this: http://localhost:8080/JEE_Learning/testingJSP
it works fine, the parameter is there.

But when I enter a JSP filename: http://localhost:8080/JEE_Learning/testing.jsp
the parameter is null.

web.xml:

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>testingJSP</servlet-name>
  <jsp-file>/testing.jsp</jsp-file>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>name</param-name>
    <param-value>John</param-value>
  </init-param>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>testingJSP</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/testingJSP</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

inside JSP file:

```
<%= getInitParameter("name") %>
```

Why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add

```
<%=getServletConfig().getServletName()%>
```

to the JSP page you will see the output

- `testingJSP` when calling `.../testingJSP` and
- `jsp` when calling `.../testing.jsp` (in Tomcat).

So the first request invokes the `testingJSP` servlet the second the JSP servlet of the container. Accordingly the servlet init parameter is only defined in the first request.

Comment: Your answer led me to this: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5892340/5459498) which calrified it completely for me. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access the name parameter from
http://localhost:8080/JEE_Learning/testingJSP    and
http://localhost:8080/JEE_Learning/testing.jsp
then you should add

```
<url-pattern>/testing.jsp</url-pattern>
```

to your

```
<servlet-mapping>
```